# Turn an array into a string for context.fillColor?

Tags: javascript, string, canvas

I want to create random particles on a canvas. However, im unable to supply each particle with a randomly determined RGB color value, its not reading my fillStyle.

Can someone please assist ?

EDIT: JSBIN example
http://jsbin.com/puworu/4/edit?js,console,output#J:L65

```
  var rgb = [];
      rgb.push(Math.round(Math.random()*255));
      rgb.push(Math.round(Math.random()*255));
      rgb.push(Math.round(Math.random()*255));

  context.fillStyle = '"rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')"';
```

Comment: Why is `rgb(...)` in quotes?

Comment: Because according to my research, it needs to be. fillStyle requires a full string.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Why is it quoted twice? It should be either `"rgb(...)"` or `'rgb(...)'` but not both.

Comment: Because when im mixing variables and text together, i need to wrap them to get the correct string result.

Comment: Uh... that's not how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a typo. The "" should not be there. It should be:

```
//context.fillStyle = '"rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')"';
context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
```

Happy coding!

**EDIT:** I've looked at your jsbin and it throws a huge number of errors all the time.

The reason is: when you call `draw(particles)` the first time from `init()` you passed the particles array from init.

But, in `setIntervalID = setInterval(function(){draw()})` no arguments is passed. A solution would be clearing the interval `clearInterval(setIntervalID)` or passing an new array to `draw()`

Comment: Or `fillStyle = 'rgb(' + rgb.join(',') + ')'`. A bit shorter and hopefully not too expensive regarding performance, but I don't think so.

Comment: Use "rgb(" + rgb.join() + ")" instead of specifying each index.

Comment: Yeah, youre right. But i think the problem was the errors also.